# Is possible use Laravel and JWT without Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have a problem with Laravel 5.8, I'm using Laravel without Eloquent because I need connect me to API and my model get data from this API and not a database local. I mean that

```
    Laravel Backend -> GetDataFromOtherAPI
```

The problem is that Tymon\JWTAuth use Auth\User and this use database local and not a API.

Is possible indeed database connection User, JWTAuth will use a Api?